# Looking for a code that finds all colors within two colors and applies them in a script within a range

Tags: pine-script

I have found a bunch of these threads for other languages but none related to Pine.

Thanks a lot for anybody who can help!

I am looking for a code that assigns all colors between two basic colors to a numerical range.

For example, let's say I have a range between 0 and 0.4. 
0 = violet
0.4 = blue. 
How do I tell Pine to find 30 colors between those two to make a nice gradient?

```
shade1(val) =>
    if val<=-0.97
        redc2
    else
        if val <=-0.93
            redder2
        else
            if val <=-0.9
                red2
```

This option below doesnt really work in Pine ...

```
  var colorArray = [];
var startColor = #18AED5;`
var endColor   = #1E1E26;`
// Calculate Colors...`
```

Answer (score 0):

Pine doesn't support dynamic creation of such rgb-colors. So it's possible to set only manually:

```
//@version=3
study("My Script")

getColor(val) =>
    val >= 0 and val < 0.1 ? #18AED5 :
 val >= 0.1 and val < 0.2 ? #18AEE5 :
 val >= 0.2 and val < 0.3 ? #18AEF5 :
 white


plot(close, color=getColor(close - close[1]))
```

Comment: if i add more colors after your #18AED5 : , will it pick colors in order within the range?
so if i do   'val >= 0 and val < 0.1 ? X : Y : Z :' etc. 
will it put them in order from 0 to 0.1 ?

Comment: No, for any value in a range [0..0.1) the color #18AED5 will be picked. If a value is outside the range [0..0.1), next condition (val >= 0.1 and val < 0.2) will be checked. It's the same like in your example with `ifs`. But you are free to put more condtiotions for value's ranges. Or maybe I got wrong your commentary.